# Filter rows which contain a list with continous values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Hi I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
    starttime                     endtime                                        positions
0   2019-05-16 05:34:26.870 2019-05-16 05:34:41.721 [7, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24...
1   2019-05-16 05:33:56.143 2019-05-16 05:34:10.995 [9, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23...
2   2019-05-16 05:33:35.659 2019-05-16 05:33:50.510 [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 2...
3   2019-05-16 05:33:04.933 2019-05-16 05:33:19.784 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,...
4   2019-05-16 05:34:11.507 2019-05-16 05:34:26.358 [3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...
```

I want to take the rows such that the list contains a continous values that is of the form `list(range(min(val),max(val)))`.

I tried

`df[df["positions"] == list(range(min(df["positions"],max(df["positions"]))))]`

But I get the error as follows:

> ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

Is it because each list have different length? How can I solve it if it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `.apply` on the column of lists:

```
df['position'].apply(lambda x: x == list(range(min(x), max(x) + 1)))
```

#### Minimal Example

```
# Example input
df = pd.DataFrame({'starttime': list(range(3)), 
                   'endtime': list(range(1, 4)), 
                   'positions': None})

# Manually insert lists into the 'positions' column entries
df.iat[0, 2] = [1, 4, 9]
df.iat[1, 2] = list(range(6))
df.iat[2, 2] = list(range(-4, 3))

# Get a boolean Series
df['positions'].apply(lambda x: x == list(range(min(x), max(x) + 1)))

0    False
1     True
2     True
```

Comment: How can 'apply' be used here, We want to filter data ryt? Not edit the "positions" columns!

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I totally misread your requirements. I've just edited my answer.